# Maintaining SQLite databases in Laraval - Adding foreign-key constraint to existing table omitted

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, eloquent, foreign-keys

While running Laravel (v8.75) with SQLite I encounter problems creating a new foreign-key relation to the existing users table.

Migrations:

```
// New model UserType
Schema::create('user_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('id');
    $table->string('name');
});

// Existing model User
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_type_id')->after('id');
    $table->foreign('user_type_id')->references('id')->on('user_types');   <----- is not being created!
});
```

The migration runs successfully, but the foreign-key constraint is missing.

During my web researches I found a related issue report on Github:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24876

I can read there, that SQLite officially not supports altering table constraints:
https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

*> Other kinds of ALTER TABLE operations such as ALTER COLUMN, ADD CONSTRAINT, and so forth are omitted.*

When the foreign-key constraint is created in the create-process of the table, then the foreign-key gets created fine!

The strange thing about this issue is, that with "DB Browser for SQLite" it is (!) possible to add a new foreign-key constraint also to the existing users table successfully!

Therefore I don't get, why it is not working in any way with Laravel...

Addittion, config database shows enabled foreign-key support:

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
    'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
],
```

Do you guys have an idea, how to get such afterwards migrations to work automatically via a Laravel migration?
Or is it really the last option to migrate productive data in a newly created db structure?

Any practical experience and tips on this topic would be helpful...
Thank you.

Comment: i can only comment that i currently cannot add a foreign key to an existing sqlite table using DB Browser - the software doesn't allow the 'Write Changes' button to become available after using the GUI to add a foreign key. So it may be tha tit appears that you can, but i haven't had any success actually executing the statement and saving it.

Comment: As this is a rather old issue, I just can comment, I was using Version 3.11.2 of DB Browser and it was still possible to add a foreign key constraint to an existing table with data. Maybe check the existing data, that the keys are valid and existing in the referenced table... Maybe this will help.